# Delpoying play application on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

i have some problem with deploying play + java application on Heroku. Deploying to heroku successful but Application error. Logs :

> -----> Play 2.x - Java app detected
>
> -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
>
> -----> Running: sbt compile stage
>   [info] Loading global plugins from /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/.sbt_home/plugins
>
> [info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
>
> [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project
>
> [info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
>
> [info] Set current project to AttractionPark (in build file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/)
>
> [info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
>
> [info] Compiling 15 Scala sources to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
>
> [info] Done compiling.
>
> [success] Total time: 17 s, completed Jan 15, 2018 8:15:24 PM
>
> [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/attractionpark_2.12-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
>
> [info] Done packaging.
>
> [info] Wrote /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/attractionpark_2.12-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
>
> [info] Main Scala API documentation to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/api...
>
> [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/attractionpark_2.12-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
>
> [info] Done packaging.
>
> [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/attractionpark_2.12-1.0-SNAPSHOT-web-assets.jar ...
>
> [info] Done packaging.
>
> model contains 60 documentable templates
>
> [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
>
> [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/attractionpark_2.12-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
>
> [info] Done packaging.
>
> [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.12/attractionpark_2.12-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar ...
>
> [info] Done packaging.
>
> [success] Total time: 11 s, completed Jan 15, 2018 8:15:36 PM
>
> [INFO] [01/15/2018 20:15:36.324] [Thread-2] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
>
> -----> Dropping ivy cache from the slug
>
> -----> Dropping sbt boot dir from the slug
>
> -----> Dropping compilation artifacts from the slug
>
> -----> Discovering process types
>   Procfile declares types -> console, web
>
> -----> Compressing...
>   Done: 98.1M
>
> -----> Launching...
>   Released v5
>
> https://kursovya.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

build.sbt :

> name := """AttractionPark"""
>
> version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
>
> lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
>
> scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
>
> libraryDependencies += guice
>
> routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>
> jdbc,
>
> javaCore,
>
> "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.3",
>
> javaWs,
>
> ws
>
> )
>
> enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
>
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.1"
>
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer-guice" % "6.0.1"
>
> val appDependencies = Seq(
>
> "com.github.scribejava" % "scribejava-apis" % "5.0.0",
>
> filters
>
> )
>
> // Testing libraries for dealing with CompletionStage...
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.assertj" % "assertj-core" % "3.6.2" % Test
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.awaitility" % "awaitility" % "2.0.0" % Test
>
> // Make verbose tests
>
> testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a", "-v"))

I use play 2.6 + java. On localhost it's worked, database on clever-cloud

P.S.

> heroku logs -t
>
> 2018-01-15T21:55:33.092875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2018-01-15T21:55:37.941657+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command
>   target/universal/stage/bin/play-getting-started -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
>   2018-01-15T21:55:40.157779+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
>   defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
>   2018-01-15T21:55:40.158289+00:00 app[web.1]: bash:
>   target/universal/stage/bin/play-getting-started: No such file or
>   directory 2018-01-15T21:55:40.252199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2018-01-15T21:55:40.236976+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127

P.S.S. I decided this problem, i have diffrent names between heroku application and play application

Comment: what is the error ? Do you have something else in the heroku logs ?

Comment: No, in logs are ok, it's problem, because i don't understand where is a mistake

Comment: Run `heroku logs -t` and then in another terminal run `heroku ps:restart`. Share the output here. The logs you're showing are build logs, and they are successful.